# Preventing Visual Studio 2017 debugger from confusing static variables with equal name

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I have observed the following phenonem in the VS 2017 debugger:
if there are two static variables of the same name and type in different files, it confuses the two.

pseudo code of variable declarations

file A:
static char msg[2048];

file B:
static char msg[64];

if I debug file B the debugger shows the contents of file A's msg.

My *guess* would be that the case of equally named static variables was not foreseen when the debugger was developed and which variable it shows depends on the compilation order.

**Question:**
how can the VS 2017 debugger be "forced" to access the static variables of the currently debugged file *without* changing the code that is being debugged?

The trivial advice of renaming the variables is not an option for me and IMHO also not in the spirit of *static* variables.

Answer (score 3):

This is the same issue reported under [VS2019 Debugger Confused by multiple variables with same name](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs2019-debugger-confused-by-multiple-variables-wit/527422), and fixed in VS 2019 version 16.8 back in Nov '20.

Unfortunately, there is no current or planned backport of the fix to VS 2017, per [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs2019-debugger-confused-by-multiple-variables-wit/527422#T-N1239797-N1247464) MSFT reply.

One workaround proposed in [another comment](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs2019-debugger-confused-by-multiple-variables-wit/527422#T-N1239797) for VS 2017 is to lookup the memory address of the target variable, then [watch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/watch-and-quickwatch-windows?view=vs-2019) it with the appropriate cast.